# Angularjs : Filter conditionaly

Tags: angularjs

```
 <div class="district-list" ng-repeat="office in offices | filter : {'DisplayOffice' : officeLocationLevelList.searchText}|limitTo:1">
```

Have a multilevel list of data. depending on the condition i want to filter the data.(First Level/ inner level). If the first level is selected then i have to search with one json attribute and if the inner level is selected then search with another json attribute. I have set it in a scope variable. How can use scope variable instead of '**DisplayOffice**'

Answer (score 1):

you can bind a function to filter which returns the filter condition using scope variables.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'name1'
      },{
        id: 2,
        name: 'name2'
      },{
        id: 3,
        name: 'name3'
      },{
        id: 3,
        name: 'aaaaa'
      }
    ];
    
    $scope.getCondition = function() {
      var obj = {};
      obj[$scope.key] = $scope.value;
      return obj;
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  Key: <input type="text" ng-model="key">
  Value: <input type="text" ng-model="value">
  <div ng-repeat="item in data | filter: {[key]:value}">
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

and there is another way while using ES6' new feature `{[key]: value}`, but this may now work for some browsers.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.$watch("key", function() {
      console.log({[$scope.key]:$scope.value});
    });
    $scope.$watch("value", function() {
      console.log({[$scope.key]:$scope.value});
    });
    $scope.data = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'name1'
      },{
        id: 2,
        name: 'name2'
      },{
        id: 3,
        name: 'name3'
      },{
        id: 3,
        name: 'aaaaa'
      }
    ];
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  Key: <input type="text" ng-model="key">
  Value: <input type="text" ng-model="value">
  
  <div ng-repeat="item in data | filter: {[key]: value}">
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can i set it in template without these functions?

Comment: Thanks. But I got the ans :)

Comment: @ShriyaR that's ok. if you have found some better solutions, you can edit to your question or even post an answer.

Comment: have added a condition in filter for enabling and disabling the filter. <div class="district-list" ng-repeat="office in offices | filter : !officeLocationLevelList.locationLevelSelected.single_level && {'DistrictDisplay' : officeLocationLevelList.searchText}|limitTo:1">

Comment: actually i have a multilevel list of data. depending on the condition i want to filter the data.(First Level/ inner level filter)

Comment: @ShriyaR man... you didn't mentioned such things in your question, how could other know all about this. anyway that's ok, glad you have found a solution.